# How can I click the close button in Gmail with Python + Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I want to click on the button to close the message that is being written.
[image]

I try with this code, but it does not work for me:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="Cerrar"]').click()
```

Can you help me? Thanks very much.

Comment: maybe element is in `<iframe>` and then it needs `driver.switch_to.frame(...)`

Comment: Ok, how would you do it completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to click this element: `//img[@alt="Close"]`
So, the Selenium python command to do this is

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@alt="Close"]').click()
```

Comment: It works in the following way: `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@alt="Cerrar"]').click()`

Comment: You should change the `.close()` to the `.click()`. I am to blame, I was wrong when writing it

Comment: Sorry about the `close()`, I had to pay attention, not just to copy-paste it. As about the "Cerrar" vs "Close" it seems to be the languages differences between our browser settings

Answer (score 1):

unless your code needs to use selenium i think that pyautogui would be better for this. it can move your mouse to a specific coordinate or look for the close button and then click it

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.moveTo(x=(your x), y=(your y))
pyautogui.click()
```

i dont know much about selenium so im sorry i cant use that to help you but i hope this helps.

Comment: I know, but it is not very efficient because I don't have to move the mouse, in fact I am running it right now because I have no other option

Comment: `pyautogui.click(button='left', clicks=1, x=960, y=265)`

Answer (score 1):

#### The built-in method `close`:

> The `close()` method is used to close the current browser window on which the focus is set, on the other hand, the `quit()` method essentially calls the driver. dispose of a method that successively closes all the browser windows and ends the WebDriver session graciously.

##### You want to use `click` when interacting with elements

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="Cerrar"]').click()
```

If that doesn't work, please share the HTML code.